# How to integrate 3D secure on Xamarin.Forms with Stripe?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, stripes

I had integrated a payment method with stripe on a Xamarin.Forms application that works only for payments that don't require 3D secure.

Today I'm looking to integrate the 3D secure part on my Xamarin.Forms application but the Stripe documentation does not provide any information for Xamarin.Forms.

For the moment my application create a TokenService before payment and then a ChargeService to make a payment.

Comment: There's no official Stripe Xamarin integration, but this 3rd party library might help you: https://github.com/DamianMehers/XamarinStripe

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have implemented the payment system, but when I make a result.NextAction?.RedirectToUrl?.Url to display the auth page it returns me null.

Comment: Also if you use WebView, it wont be able to redirect back to your app, only if you open the 3d URL from a native browser, then it will be able to return to "youtappurl://"